# jest error "Cannot use import statement outside" with esm package?

Tags: javascript, npm, jestjs, babeljs

I was using this package https://auto-animate.formkit.com, everything was doing fine but I got this error running jest
[image]

repo: https://github.com/ming2024/boilerplate-vite-react

I have no idea what's wrong. Can someone point me to a direction for the error?

Comment: What is this file's extension ? you can use mere `.js` file, or use `.mjs` (for extension) or `.cjs` for common js. If you are using `.js` you may try setting property `"type": "module"` in your `package.json`.

Comment: @Paul-Marie it's a jest related issue though, It has nothing to do with my app. `.mjs` is the package extension